# python selenium cannot send string to website

Tags: python, selenium, find, element

I need to type some text in online notepad but cannot find the right element to send it.You can find whole page [here](https://note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/5689eb9716c4ec19ae1c441ce67fbf46?page=1)

I try:   `fox.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tinymce']/p")`

but error occured:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='tinymce']/p"}

Also I try:
`fox.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'Working')]")` no errors but it didnt type the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 'notepad' is in an `iframe`, you first need to switch to the specific frame. Try this:

```
fox.switch_to.frame(fox.find_element_by_id("page_text_ifr"))
notepad = fox.find_element_by_id("tinymce")
notepad.send_keys("Hello World!")
```

Or since you use XPath:

```
fox.switch_to.frame(fox.get_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='page_text_ifr']")
notepad = fox.get_element_by_xpath("//body[@id='tinymce']")
notepad.send_keys("Hello World!")
```